# How to set stereotype on class parameter or method in MetaPOST

Tags: metapost, metauml

I want to be able to set event stereotype on a method, inside a class. I've read through the documentation, but found nothing on this subject.

As shown below, the `<<<event>>>` part is shown as another parameter

It would be great if the output could be something similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/24693930/4788850.

Added a feature request in the project, but need a workaround for now.
https://github.com/ogheorghies/MetaUML/issues/13

---

```
input metauml;

beginfig(1);
    Class.Bootstrapper
    ("Bootstrapper")
    ("+app: Application",
    "+container: Container",
    "<<event>>", 
    "+cancel: CancelEventHandler")
    ("+Shutdown(): bool");

    drawObject(Bootstrapper);

endfig;
end;
```

[image: Generated output from above code]

Comment: `classStereotypes.Bootstrapper("<<event>>");`? ([code](https://termbin.com/i8pb), [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nj1VC.png))

Comment: Yes, that sets the class stereotype, but not for a single method. See provided stackoverflow link

Comment: That doesn't seem to be implemented. I had a look at the MetaUML implementation and it is rather non-trivial (at least for me).  However, judging from the commit log on GitHub, MetaUML is very actively developed so I expect the maintainer to respond to your issue soon.